# Cannot download files on Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8, performance, download

I can not download files in Windows 8.1.

First, downlaod speed decreases to 10-20KB/s. Than it drops to zero. I think it is about security settings. But I could not detect which setting cause this.

I googled it, but neither of solutions worked for me.

**Specs:**
My computer is a desktop PC with ethernet connection. It was downloading files perfectly 1-2 days ago. Now, it changed behavior.

Since I could not install my sound card driver, I have disabled group policies (or something else I could not remember) because the driver was not certificate. I did this the day I installed Windows 8 (this saturday)

I removed the anti-virus program (Avast).

I got 2.1MB/s when downloading torrent but 10Kb/s when downloading a file.

**Tried Solutions:**

- Disabled Large Send OffLoad and Checksum offload
- Flushed DNS
- Changed power settings to maximum

The files I tried to download:
http://dfn.dl.sourceforge.net/project/choco/choco/2.1.5/choco-2.1.5.zip
http://www.diku.dk/~rfonseca/ProGAL/ProGAL.jar

Comment: Please provide more information.  Is this a personal computer?  Nothing by in a default installation of Windows would explain this behavior.  Are you saying it does work then, then suddenly, does not work?

Comment: "I googled it, but neither of solutions worked for me" doesn't help us any, nor does it count as showing research effort. :)  What solutions did you try exactly?  What were the results?  Does it behave the same way in Safe Mode? How about when logged in as a different user?  Did it EVER work right?

Comment: Sorry for the lack of information @techie007. I updated it now.

Comment: No problems, but can you answer these two though: Does it behave the same way in Safe Mode? How about when logged in as a different user?  Additionally, if it worked 3 days ago, have you tried using a System Restore to go back to 3 days ago? If you're using a router between you and your ISP's equipment, have you tried removing it from the setup and hooking the PC to the ISP's equipment directly?

Comment: @techie007 After finishing my downloads (if I can), I will try those and post the results.